# React stop react from downloading react dev tools

Tags: reactjs

I used `create-react-app` for this project and I already deployed to production on netlify as production build. Problem is that it keeps downloading this script from devtools which is almost half of 1MB. How can i stop it from using this file in production? I tried install the npm package `disable-react-devtools` and added it in index.js but this doesn't do anything apparently, file still being downloaded

```
...
import { disableReactDevTools } from '@fvilers/disable-react-devtools';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    disableReactDevTools();
}
...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your index.html file and it will disable the React DevTools before any react code is accessed

```
<script>
    if (typeof window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ === 'object') {
        __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.inject = function() {};
    }
</script>
```